# Log4j2 Alternate to monitorInterval="30"

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Recently I have upgraded log4j which made a lot of changes. In our project to enable the Automatic Reconfiguration for the log4j-1, we had used DOMConfiguration.configureandWatch().

To enable this privilege in log4j2, as per the documentation we can use **montiorInterval** in Configuration part of log4j2.xml. [Automatic Reconfiguration-log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

But I like to know whether this can be done via any log4j2 API method like Domconfiguration in log4j-1?

Comment: You don't provide enough information to really answer this question. What are you really trying to accomplish? Why do you need to load the configuration as opposed to letting Log4j do it?

Comment: Thanks, rgoers for the comment.. (sry for the confusion.. edited the description now). But I don't know what information is need for this... I just like to know whether the Automatic Reconfiguration in log4j2 can be done via any API method like  Domconfiguration in log4j-1?

Comment: I am trying to understand why specifying monitorInterval in the configuration is insufficient. Calling Log4j to reconfigure can certainly be done, but that is not "automatic".

Comment: Thanks rgoers. I don't say this as Insufficient. But think this scenario consider we have 30 log4j2.xml which will be assigned to a specific daemon at start fn . Instead of adding monitorInterval in 30 xml file ...why can't we add some method at start fn

Comment: For the same reason you aren't using 1 configuration file for all 30. To allow each one to have its own configuration. If you like, the monitorInterval can be specified as a Lookup. You could code it as monitorInterval="${sys:monitorInterval:-30}". Then if you provide a system property named monitorInterval that will be used, otherwise it will default to 30.

Answer (score 2):

Every configuration in Log4j includes  a `WatchManager`. The `WatchManager` allows you to watch files for changes or urls (typically HTTP). The Watcher you provide will have its `modified` method called when a modification to the target occurs. You can use this to monitor any files, not just Log4j configuration files.

Log4j automatically creates the WatchManager and registers one or more Watchers as it is creating the Configuration based on the setting of the monitorInterval in the configuration file and whether you are using more than one configuration file. If you create your own custom Configuration you can call `the initializeWatchers` method in `AbstractConfiguration`, or you could extract the relevant code out of that method and call it in some other code.